# Authentication for .NET Core MVC application running in AWS Lambda does not work when serving CSS and JS files

Tags: aws-lambda, asp.net-core-mvc, amazon-cloudfront

I have been chasing down this issue for **months** and yesterday I finally made some progress.

I have a .NET Core MVC application I am uploading to AWS Lambda using the AWS visual studio tool. I am using a simple login form (any username/pw works) with cookie authentication.

I have been getting random logouts, and assumed I had an issue with my authentication setup in Startup.cs. It's not that. It's the linked CSS and JS files in my **_Layout.cs** file. If I remove them or use inline scripts it works.

Here is a gif of the behavior I am seeing:

https://gfycat.com/unrulyableermine

I would note that I am intermittently logged BACK in when clicking on the top links, almost like it's switching between two different instances and I'm only logged into one.

[Here](https://github.com/mcblakeb/aws-login-test) Is the source on github. It can be reproduced only when actually published to a new lambda function, not locally.

Here is my Layout file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - AWS Auth Test</title>
    @*INLIE SEEMS TO WORK*@
    @*@await Html.PartialAsync("_InlineStyle")*@
    @* LINKED CSS causing logout (rarely) *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a asp-page="/Index" class="navbar-brand">AWSLoginTest</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-route="First">Auth Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-route="Second">Auth Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @* THESE are causing logouts. *@
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using our ASP.NET Core DataProtection provider, https://github.com/aws/aws-ssm-data-protection-provider-for-aspnet, with your application? ASP.NET Core's DataProtection framework is used to make sure cookies and anti forgery tokens are valid. By default ASP.NET Core DataProtection generates crypto keys in memory and uses those. That works in a debug environment but in production where you have more then one compute environment serving traffic you need something to keep the crypto keys in sync across the compute environments. The **Amazon.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SSM** NuGet package is an easy way to do that.

Comment: I didn't have a lot of luck with the ssm package, but I was able to use AspNetCore.DataProtection.Aws.S3 to get this working from your suggestion and the article at https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-data-protection/. Thanks for your help! Documentation about setting up cookies within lambda in .net core seems pretty few and far between.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'm curious why you couldn't get the ssm package to work. Could you open an issue on our repo just to give some ideas what wasn't working. https://github.com/aws/aws-ssm-data-protection-provider-for-aspnet